# Access 2016 Form auto-populate based on another field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've got two  tables that contain the following.

**Table Name: Enquiries**

- ID
- Username
- Date of Raising
- Time of Escalation
- Invoice
- Repeat Contact
- Query Type
- Context of Query
- DC

**Table Name: PC**

- PCID
- PCarea
- Town
- DCArea
- DCName

I currently have a Form setup with the above fields all selected. I have PCArea setup as a drop down as the field has 2000+ records (Postcodes). What I want is when a person updates this field/drop down/combo box for Access to lookup the PCArea and find out what the DCName is relevant to this and then populate the DC field in "Enquiries" and show on the form but I can't fathom how to do it.

I know it's VBA related but I can't seem to get the format right?

```
Private Sub Combo472_AfterUpdate()

Me.PCArea = Me.Data.Column(9)

End Sub
```

Sure didn't work! Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace {PCAreaDropDown} with name of your dropdown box, and all you really need is the one field in there.  It looks like you threw at least 10 columns (9+1) based on your example.

```
me!DC = dlookup("DCName","PC", "PCArea = '" & me!PcAreaDropDown & "'"
```

Comment: Looks like that solution is creating a syntax error. I've changed it to the following (As you advised) `me!DC = dlookup("DCName","PC", "PCArea = '" & me.Combo472 & "'"` @geeFlo

Comment: Is it a zip code or postal?  If it's numeric, then get rid of the single quotes in the PCArea string.   Also make sure the me!DC statement is referencing the fieldname on the form you are updating.

Comment: it's a postal code so it's Alphanumeric. The DC Statement? Are you referring to the me!DC = Dlookup part? It's aimed at a form called "CU/DC view" but given this is already on the form does that matter?

Comment: `Private Sub Combo472_AfterUpdate()
Me!DC = DLookup("DCName", "PC", "PCArea = '" & Me.Combo472 & "'")
End Sub` Is how it is currently looking. When I run it not it's asking me to input something into the Data.DC field... which almost feels mad given that's what it's job is!

Comment: and the PC table contains both the DCNAME and corresponding PCArea fields right?   My guess is that Combo472 might be returning the index of that field.  Check to see if it contains more than just the one column for the PCArea.  If not, then you may need to specify the ".column(1)" or whatever column is not the index (0).

Comment: Yup it does. It's got `(ID, PCArea, Town, DCarea, DCName). On "Row Source"` I've got the following... `SELECT [PC].[ID], [PC].[PCArea] FROM PC ORDER BY [PCArea];` as the drop down. So I can't fathom where the heck it isn't working. Unless it's because the dropdown doesn't have the DCName in there? Just the Postcode? @geeFlo

Comment: You don't need DCname in there.  In fact you can even get rid of PC.id from that dropdown.  All you need is one single bound field - PCArea.

Comment: Or just make the PCArea column the bound column in your properties for the dropdown.

Comment: IT WORKS. Thanks dude. Turns out is was the binding column that was causing issues. Sorry for being a stupid, thanks for your help. Have a nice day.

Comment: No prob.  We've all been there.